# Is it possible to create two edit text in showAlert Dialog?

Tags: java, android-studio

I just want to know if it is possible to create another edit text below my existing one and how to create it. The new one should also have a subtitle above the text line so users can differentiate which one is which. Thanks and have a great day.

```
private void showAlertDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Cart.this);
        alertDialog.setTitle("Requests:");
        alertDialog.setMessage("(Condiments,napkins, take-out orders or such can also be requested here)");

        final EditText edtAddress = new EditText(Cart.this);
        final EditText edtRef = new EditText(Cart.this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        );
        edtAddress.setLayoutParams(lp);
        alertDialog.setView(edtAddress);// Request Edit Txt
        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp);

        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Confirm", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //Create new Request
                Request request = new Request(
                        Common.currentTable.getTablet(),
                        edtAddress.getText().toString(),
                        txtTotalPrice.getText().toString(),
                        cart
                );
                // Submit to Firebase
                requests.child(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                        .setValue(request);
                //Delete cart
                new Database(getBaseContext()).cleanCart();
                Toast.makeText(Cart.this, "Order Placed Thank You and Kindly Wait for your Order.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
        });
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: most likely yes, by writing the code

Comment: Only if it's your own component (your code), not by default Alert class from javafx or swing.

Comment: @ill create custom alert dialog and extend it to `Alert Dialog`. See this https://parzibyte.me/blog/en/2019/08/28/custom-alert-dialog-android/